# Strange behaviour of Python list() function with a file object argument

Tags: python, list, file

Trying to pass a file object to `list` function cannot get the list of file objects.

```
x = open('example.txt', 'rb')
y = list(x)
```

And the output is `y = ['aaaaa']`, whereas I expected to get a list of file objects: `[<open file 'example.txt', mode 'rb' at 0x7fa03ced1300>]` containing only one element, of course. Why `list` function have transformed its argument here?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what behavior you _expect_ here?  What do you mean by "cannot get the list of file objects"?

Comment: If you were expecting a one-element list whose one element is the file object, that'd be `[x]`. Calling `list` on a thing doesn't put the thing in a list; it builds a list out of the thing's *elements*.

Comment: This code gives the *content* of the file, as a list of lines. Like mgilson, I don't understand what else you expected.

Comment: @mgilson I have extended my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating through a file object iterates through the lines in the file.

Usual usage:

```
for line in f:
    # do something with the line
```

The argument to `list` constructor is an iterable. The argument will be iterated and the list will be created from iterated items.

Usage example:

```
list('abc')  # result: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

That combined, `list(f)` creates a list of lines read from the file.

To actually create a list containing one file object do this:

```
list_of_files = [f]
```